# Access 2007 - Weekens

Tags: date, ms-access-2007

I have a module called CntDays(date1,date2).

When I run this query, everything works fine:

```
SELECT MAX(cont.status) as raStatus, 
       MIN(cont.receipt_time) as startDate, 
       MAX(cont.insp_time_c) AS stopDate,
       CntDays(DateValue(MIN(cont.receipt_time)),DateValue(MAX(cont.insp_time_c))) AS days, 
       comments.comments AS comments, 
       comments.exempt AS exempt 
FROM cont, comments
WHERE cont.ra = comments.ra
GROUP BY cont.ra, comments.comments, comments.exempt
```

However, if run this query:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT cont.ra,  
              MAX(cont.status) as raStatus, 
              MIN(cont.receipt_time) as startDate, 
              MAX(cont.insp_time_c) AS stopDate,
              CntDays(DateValue(MIN(cont.receipt_time)),DateValue(MAX(cont.insp_time_c))) AS days, 
              comments.comments AS comments, 
              comments.exempt AS exempt 
FROM cont, comments
WHERE cont.ra = comments.ra
GROUP BY cont.ra, comments.comments, comments.exempt
```

I keep getting this error message:

```
          Data type mismatch in criteria expression.
```

The only difference between the two is the "Distinct cont.ra" statement. 
I am not knowledgeable enough to know how to resolve this.

Comment: So removed DISTINCT and it works. Just not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

I removed DISTINCT and it worked.